# Flask-SocketIO server deploys to Heroku giving me connection error

Tags: javascript, flask, heroku, socket.io

I am trying to work with flask and flask-socketio framework. It works perfectly fine while running on my local machine but when deployed to heroku it is giving me this connection error.

> ```
>     websocket.js:87 WebSocket connection to 'wss://counselai1.herokuapp.com/socket.io/EIO=4&transport=websocket'> failed:
> ```

This is the code of my server:

```
 CORS(app, resources={r"/": {"origins": "wss://counselai1.herokuapp.com"}})
    socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="wss://counselai1.herokuapp.com")
```

My Procfile is :

```
 web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 app:app
```

The code for the js to connect the socket to my domain:

```
var socket = io.connect('wws://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
```